# Read parameters - POCO C++

Tags: html, visual-c++, post, get, poco-libraries

I am a beginner, trying to learn how to use POCO C++ library ( http://pocoproject.org/ )

Suppose I have an HTML which has some input elements (say a text-box, check-box, etc.)

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <form action="xyz.html" method="GET">
 <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" />
 <input type="submit" />
 </form>
 </body>
 <html>
```

After hitting the submit button, how do I read these values at the server side from the request object?

Could anyone please also explain how to this is done when POST method is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out the `HTTPFormServer` sample project provided with the POCO libraries.
It shows how to read form parameters both with GET and POST methods.

Basically it extends the abstact class `HTTPRequestHandler`.
In the override of the `handleRequest()` method, it uses `MessageHeader::splitParameters()` to parse the form parameters.

Once you have downloaded the library, you can find the sample in:
`<install_dir>\Net\samples\HTTPFormServer`

Answer (score 1):

This shuld work

```
// parse html form 
HTMLForm form( request );
NameValueCollection::ConstIterator iterator = form.begin();
while (iterator != form.end()){
   BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << iterator->first << ": " << iterator->second;
   iterator++;
}
```

Hope it helps.